# Python Virtual environment [Some of the python libraries is getting installed out of virtual environment directory]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, virtualenv

Scenario:
We are creating virtual environment and installing all the requirement.txt files but few files are getting created outside the directory.

Use case:
We want to zip this environment and want to use it for spark driver and executors

Problem:
Since few files are getting installed out of virtual environment directory, hence spark is failing with module not found exception or **lib*.so** file not available.

Comment: Virtual environments are not designed to be transferred from one machine to the other. Your example shows one of the reasones for it.

Comment: It's us who make a sense out of it, the use case is to deploy the same product at multiple environment and it's better to use this approach to make your product independent of an environment.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I applied certain steps:

Written a blog:
https://kshitij-kuls.com/2019/08/04/setting-up-virtual-environment-for-pyspark/

Before we proceed it's require to understand the basic structure of python:

```
├── bin
│   ├── activate
│   ├── activate.csh
│   ├── activate.fish
│   ├── activate_this.py
│   ├── easy_install
│   ├── easy_install-3.6
│   ├── pip
│   ├── pip3
│   ├── pip3.6
│   ├── python
│   ├── python-config
│   ├── python3 -> python
│   ├── python3.6 -> python
│   └── wheel
├── include
│   └── python3.6m -> /usr/include/python3.6m
├── lib
│   └── python3.6
|       ├── site-packages
│       ├── lib-dynload -> /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload [Dynamic Library]
```

Environment Variables:

`PYSPARK_PYTHON : Points to the executable python file: bin/python`

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH : Points to the dynamic library path: lib/python3.6/lib-dynload [All .so* files]`

PYTHONPATH : Points to the installed packages within virtual environment as well as the dynamic library path : `lib/python3.6/site-packages<CPS>lib/python3.6/lib-dynload [All .py files]`

PYTHONHOME : Points to the python library path: lib/python3.6/site-packages

Steps to build Virtual environment:

```
Install python in the machine of desired version.
Create Virtual Env
virtualenv env -p /usr/local/bin/python3
Activate Virtual Env
source env/bin/activate
Install requirements
pip install numpy
```

Now here is the trick, you can see this 
line 
`├── lib-dynload -> /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload`
it's a symbolic link and pointing to the local machine path and hence even if you just zip this virtual environment folder then these dependencies would be missing on the cluster.
So, it's required to copy all the .so* files from `/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload`, `/usr/lib64/*.so.*`, etc... to `lib/python3.6/lib-dynload`
Copy all the .py files from `/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload`, `/usr/lib64/*.so.*`, etc... to `lib/python3.6/site-packages`.
Run it from the home dir of virtual environment in our case it's env/

```
Prepare zip
zip -rq ../venv.zip *
Upload the zip to the /udf folder for tdss: /tookitaki/tdss/udf/
```

Environmental variable setup

For driver: `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[Environment variable]`

For executor: `spark.executorEnv.[Environment variable]`

PYSPARK_PYTHON

`pyspark.spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON = venv/bin/python`
`pyspark.spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON = venv/bin/python`

PYTHONHOME

`pyspark.spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHONHOME = venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages`
`pyspark.spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHOME = venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages`

LD_LIBRARY_PATH

`pyspark.spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH = venv/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload`
`pyspark.spark.executorEnv.LD_LIBRARY_PATH = venv/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload`

PYTHONPATH

This need to included in YARN-ENV-ENTRIES, it's not getting set from the spark configs.

`PYTHONPATH = {{PWD}}/__venv__.zip<CPS>{{PWD}}/__py4j-0.10.7-src__.zip<CPS>venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages<CPS>venv/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload<CPS>`

`To run python`
`cd venv`

`export PYTHONPATH=lib64/python3.6/site-packages:lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload`

source bin/activate

Comment: Please include all relevant steps in the answer itself, not as a link to some external site.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't know what it will gonna change to paste the same thing here but take it